# Virtuemart mod_virtuemart_product sef issue

Tags: joomla3.0, virtuemart, joomla4

I have a weird problem with the virtuemart module "mod_virtuemart_product". I will refer to it as module from now on.

My shop is linked to a menu link in top nav. My frontpage contains the modules. 3 of them to be specific. The shop runs in strict mode on localhost.

The first one is a Banner-type.
The second one below is a slider type.
and the last one is just a category output of items with some styling

They are not sef yet.

Now, if I activate "show addtocart" on the last module, all links have sef except the first item of the last module.

Even with the default layout which virtuemart supplies.

Im basically trying to find a solution for this one item that is not "sefing" correctly.

Any help appreciated.

What did I do:

I activated Default layout. I expected an error on my end. But the error remained.

I activated "addtocart" on the second one and deactivated the last one. Now the first and second one are "sefing" except the first item of the second module.

Comment: Have you checked their forums? It's pretty actively maintained.  http://forum.virtuemart.net